# Smooth resizing and fade WP app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, resize, fade

I want to ask you what should i do to resize (rectangle) smoothly and fade (grid) in and out? I'm using C#, Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a loop of some sort and add

```
Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue))
```

where alpha goes from 0 to 255, so a value of 128 for your alpha will give you 50% opactity.

Then you can apply the brush

```
myRectangle.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0,0,200,300));
```

Comment: Ok, fine but i want add easing function to resize rectangle like OutQuad. How to?

Comment: @PawełMiczka change the values of new Ractangle(x-val, y-val, width, height);